# Easy Tracker issue

Tags: android, google-analytics, easytracker

I am trying to set context for easytracker before using it in my on create method as :

```
 Context context= this; 
 EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(context);
```

But getInstance is needing a context and when I call setContext, it becomes red-underlined saying "The method `setContext(Context, ParameterLoader, ServiceManager)` in the type `EasyTracker` is not applicable for the arguments `(Context)`".

I want to set context for easytracker to track my button clicks.

Comment: What is the context? An `Activity` or a `Fragment`?

Comment: Context is an Activity

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what the error is saying is that if you call getInstance() you need to provide it a Context object. You're doing this within an Activity, so getInstance(this) should work for you (in this case, this will be matching your current Context).
So Change  this

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(context);
```

to

```
EasyTracker.getInstance(context).setContext(context);
```

Or to set `easytracker` instance,try this

```
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(context);
```

and track button click event as

```
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
          .createEvent("ui_action",     // Event category (required)
                       "button_press",  // Event action (required)
                       "play_button",   // Event label
                       null)            // Event value
          .build()
      );
```

Comment: Still setContext is red underlined.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `setContext` here, just follow Google's [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/):

```
@Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ... // The rest of your onStart() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ... // The rest of your onStop() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
  }
```

Comment: My my onClick is in oncreate method, not in onstart or onstop

Comment: The EasyTracker is used to see when the screens are displayed, for events you need to create custom trackers: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events